# Apache Camel - Browse Exchanges of a SEDA queue

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel, jconsole

I'm working on a small app which uses Apache Camel with JMX active.
Very simply put, I have a route using SEDA component - just 1 consumer - which in a nutshell creates its own thread and queues incoming Exchanges if the route is busy.

Basically I'd like to monitor/browse/visualize the Exchanges that are waiting in the SEDA queue. I've tried Hawtio and JConsole with JMX but it only provides the number of total and current inflight exchanges on that given route. It doesn't mention the number of Exchanges waiting to be processed.

I've also tried the Browse component which keeps track of all exchanges being passed to the browse endpoint, however it keeps all the exchanges, as opposed as just the "queued" ones.

I'm wondering if there is something out-of-the-box in Camel which allows me to do this or if I overlooked something in Hawtio or JConsole.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that you have a single consumer thread, is the number of inflight messages minus one message currently being processed by your thread not the number of queued messages?

Comment: @Ralf I'm afraid the #inflight messages is always 1. Inflight meaning "being processed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see on the `SedaEndpoint` mbean how many messages are in the queue. You can find those in the endpoints tree in hawtio, or also in plain JMX as well.

`@ManagedAttribute(description = "Current queue size")
    public int getCurrentQueueSize() {
        return queue.size();
    }`

Comment: You are correct, I was looking at the Route instead of looking at the Endpoint. That's helpful. But how about actually inspecting Exchanges in the queue? Currently I am using a route policy which is "showing" in/out exchanges as they go. I can potentially persist them in some form but ideally I'd like some real time browse.

Comment: Actually, just realized the onExchangeBegin in the RoutePolicy won't do the trick since this callback is executed once the Exchange is taken out of the SEDA queue.

Comment: The endpoint has a browse operation you can use: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/seda/SedaEndpoint.html

Comment: Right again. Once again, Camel saved my day. Thanks.